# Can I enter my pass code when in voice over mode?

Tags: iphone, voice-dictation, voiceover

Is it possible to unlock the iPhone 4s when in voiceover mode?

I need to be able to enter my pass code in voiceover mode.

Answer (score 1):

1. Slide to Unlock at the bottom of the screen.
2. Tap the first digit of your passcode once.  VoiceOver will read the digit aloud.
3. Double-tap on that digit to enter the digit of the passcode.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 for the next three digits.
5. Your phone will now be unlocked.